# How do I include npm modules in webpack DLLs?

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to use the DLL plugins of webpack (version 1.13) to create a DLL bundle that contains all the npm modules I need for my various React projects (i.e. preact, preact-compat, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, recompose). I want to distribute the DLL bundle that contains all these npm modules via my shop's internal npm repo. Several web applications should load the DLL bundle from the npm repo and use the modules included therein.

In the example for [using DLLs in webpack from the webpack repo on GitHub](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/dll), a module named `module` is included in the alpha-DLL. `module` comes from the `node_modules` directory in the examples dir (one dir below the dll dir).

This works, when I build the example in the dll-user dir using node build.js and look at `dll-user/js/output.js`, I can see these lines:

`/*!*****************************************************************************************!*\
  !*** delegated ../node_modules/module.js from dll-reference alpha_e0d5512587ca63cbbd71 ***!
  \*****************************************************************************************/`

The module named `module` is, however not really a proper npm module, it is just a file named `module.js` sitting directly in the `node_module` directory. I tried including a “real world” npm module, in this case `preact`.

After building the `dll` and `dll-user` projects, looking at the `output.js` file, I can see that the whole code of the preact module was included in the output, there is no delegation happening.

**How do I make this work properly? Is it a bug in webpack?**

I've created a code example on GitHub based on the webpack DLL example that shows the problem: https://github.com/pahund/webpack-dll-problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Originally I only made the given example work but had no real idea how everything was supposed to be used. I wrote this (new content below the block):

---

Ok, so I think I got at least a part of it.
I will tell you what you have to do to make your example work.

There are two ways to make it work:

1. Remove `preact` from the `package.json` (and `node_modules` if necessary) of the **containing folder** i.e. the top-level. Now you have `preact` only in the `dll` folder. 
   Then change the `require` call in `example.js` within the `dll-user`
   folder to
   `require("../dll/node_modules/preact")`
   That should work but is not exactly what we want.
2. Now the other way around. Remove `preact` from the **dll** folder but install it only to the **containing** folder.
   Run both of the build scripts and see that in `output.js` is everything delegated as it should including `preact`.

---

**New:**

Ok, so after a bit more poking around here is how I *think* it works. (Since we know each other and sort-of work together fewer words would do but I think this might also help others if I am a bit more explicit on details, so bear with me.)

Preliminary remarks: I assume you want to create a dll file that you 1) can install into the project with npm and 2) somehow include with a separate script tag into your HTML. That script creates on execution a global variable that exposes a function which in turn is used by your application script to resolve dependencies.
Further, I assume that you have already a directory for the dll bundle set up with only a `package.json` and webpack ready installed.

First you create a `webpack.config.js` like this:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

module.exports= {
  entry: ["preact"], // put here every module that goes into the dll
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "index.js",
    library: "[name]_[hash]"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DllPlugin({
      path: path.join(__dirname, "[name]-manifest.json"),
      name: "[name]_[hash]" // (keep consistent with output.library)
    })
  ]
};
```

Now create the bundle and its manifest with

```
$ webpack
```

The structure of the dll project folder is now:

```
dll-project
|_ node_modules
| |_ preact
|_ main.js
|_ main-mainifest.json
|_ package.json
|_ webpack.config.js
```

Now you have installed this package into another project, your app:

```
app
|_ node_modules
| |_ dll-project
|_ index.js
|_ package.json
|_ webpack.config.js
```

*This* `webpack.config.js` looks like (or similar to) this:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports= {
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "app.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      scope: mydll,
      manifest: require("./node_modules/dll-project/main-manifest.json")
    })
  ]
};
```

In your `index.js` that is, your app code, you require modules which are in the dll bundle in this way:

```
var React = require("mydll/node_modules/preact/dist/preact");
```

If you run `webpack -d` you'll see something like the following in the generated `app.js`:

```
/* 1 */
/*!***************************************************************************************************!*\
  !*** delegated ./node_modules/preact/dist/preact.js from dll-reference main_2057857de340fdcfd8aa ***!
  \***************************************************************************************************/
```

One might ask "Why can't I just use my standard requires like `require("preact")`?". The answer is: you can, but. But in that case you would have to install all these dependencies you have in your dll bundle *also* in your app. Because in this case you would be using "mapped mode" instead of "scoped mode" (see [Webpack Docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dllreferenceplugin)).

In scoped mode you have to explicitly `require` the path to the module relative to the manifest. The upside is: You don't have to install the module (and have it as a dependency in the `package.json`) in your app.

In mapped mode you can require the module as usual (as if it were installed in your app's node_modules) but you have to install it also in the dll using app. That is because Webpack will evaluate the `require` call first and then realize that the same module is also in the dll bundle and thus render only an alias ("delegated ...") into the output.

---

Now I think there are usescases for both of these modes. The mapped mode is cool if you are only building an app-local dll to speed up your builds. In that case you would install and save all the deps that go into the dll locally anyway. But if you want to build a dll bundle as an installable module and share it between apps - and you don't want to keep track of all the modules in the dll in every single of these apps - you will most probably want to use scoped mode paying the price of more verbose `require` calls.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out your solution and get back to you.

Interestingly, the folks over at [Bilbasen](http://www.bilbasen.dk/) (mobile phone optimized version) are doing exactly what I have planned, and it works for them.

Comment: This cleared up three days of confusion. Thank you. I wish DllReferencePlugin would be modified to blindly accept what is in the manifest.json file. I don't see the need for webpack to resolve the require when it exists in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way;

```
new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
  context: process.cwd(), // Important
  manifest: manifest.json
}),
```